# What is difference in the referencing entity options while adding a relationship in a views?

Tags: 7, entities

I have entity reference field field_patient_reference. 
While adding a relationship in views I get two options : 
What is the difference between the two options below:

> **Entity Reference: Referencing entity** A bridge to the Content
>   entity that is referencing Content via field_patient_reference
>
> and
>
> **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity** A bridge to the Content
>   entity that is referenced via field_patient_reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say that Content A references Content B via an entity reference.

Content B is the **Referenced Entity**, while Content A is the **Referencing Entity**.

It really depends on what you are trying to see.  Say for example you pull a view of all content type B but want data from content A.  In that case you would use **Entity Reference: Referencing entity**.  If you have Content A and want data about Content B you would then use **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity**.